# Will Ubuntu work on the HP ENVY 17 j180ca?

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, hp

I was wondering if Ubuntu will work on my laptop. By working, I mean having the correct drivers (especially the graphics, because I do a ton of 3d design). Here are the specs:

-HP ENVY 17 j180ca (Pre installed with Windows 8.1)

-NVIDIA Geforce 840m

-Intel i7-4710MQ @ 2.50GHz

-Intel integrated HD Graphics

-12 GB RAM

If anyone has any idea if Ubuntu will recognize my drives, any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You can download Ubuntu and try it.

Comment: Okay, I downloaded it and tried it. My Intel HD graphics driver is being replaced with Haswell Mobile. I see no mention of my NVIDIA card. Using the software updater yielded no results. Any ideas?